# Как внедрить в название чекбокса ссылку?

Tags: html, css

Есть чекбокс, сбоку от него, как положено - строчка текста. Но часть этой строчки - ссылка. Как это организовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример

```html
<label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check">
      <span>Checkbox text <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/883146/Как-внедрить-в-название-чекбокса-ссылку">link</a></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Другая проблема: сам чекбокс на одной строке, а текст - на следующей

Comment: @fromillia - Покажите ваш код